# Best Practice for configuring ASP.net projects with IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I'd like some input and thoughts on the best practice for developing asp.net applications.  In previous projects we have gone to the hassle of creating a DNS name and adding an entry to the host file and then changing the web project settings to point to that address as a "Custom Web Server".

It was my understanding that this caused all the traffic to use the complete IIS system rather than a subset.  By using something other than localhost it caused IIS to fully authenticate the user and not use the internal "loopback".

It may also depend on if you set the host file entry to 127.0.0.1 or to the actual IP address of the system.

However I can't seem to find any articles on the web that really address this.

Thanks

dbl

Comment: You need to clarify your question - particularly "why" you (even) have to go through DNS motions. **IF** you have Visual Studio, it already includes it's own development server for you to do debugging on your own desktop. You can choose to install IIS Express on your desktop as well, and opt to have a web application use IIS Express instead of VS dev server.

Comment: As i said I'm looking for "Best Practices" and yes Visual Studio does come with "Cassini" so that it can be up and running very quickly.  But I don't think it would be part of any "Best Practices".  Neither would IIS Express as both of them are nothing close to what IIS is on a server.  This will lead to issues and undiscovered bugs when the applications are deployed to a server environment.  Issues like authentication and file uploads just to name a few.